# Arquillian cube : issue starting multiple images

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have a compose file which I am able to run using docker-compose command,

m-c02wt0e3htdg:arquillian-cub r0s0164$ docker-compose -f docker_compose.yml up -d

Creating network "arquillian-cub_default" with the default driver

Creating arquillian-cub_fake_1   ... done

Creating arquillian-cub_tomcat_1 ... done

m-c02wt0e3htdg:arquillian-cub r0s0164$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                   NAMES
ef8693bc7006        tutum/tomcat:7.0              "/run.sh"                10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:8181->8080/tcp                  arquillian-cub_tomcat_1

8b11de635750        cicd/my-fake-service:latest   "java -cp app:app/li…"   10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        8081-8082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9191->8080/tcp   arquillian-cub_fake_1

m-c02wt0e3htdg:arquillian-cub r0s0164$ curl -I http://localhost:8181
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 06:01:25 GMT

m-c02wt0e3htdg:arquillian-cub r0s0164$ curl -I http://localhost:9191
HTTP/1.1 404 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 06:01:35 GMT

The same docker-compose file I am specifying in arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
  http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

        <extension qualifier="docker">

                <property name="serverVersion">1.30</property>
                <property name="definitionFormat">COMPOSE</property>
                <property name="dockerContainersFile">docker_compose.yml</property>

        </extension>

</arquillian>
```

Console:

```
CubeDockerConfiguration: 
  serverVersion = 1.30
  serverUri = unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  tlsVerify = false
  dockerServerIp = localhost
  definitionFormat = COMPOSE
  clean = false
  removeVolumes = true
  dockerContainers = containers:
  tomcat:
    alwaysPull: false
    image: tutum/tomcat:7.0
    killContainer: false
    manual: false
    networkMode: arquillian-cub_default
    networks: [arquillian-cub_default]
    portBindings: !!set {8181->8080/tcp: null}
    readonlyRootfs: false
    removeVolumes: true
  fake:
    alwaysPull: false
    exposedPorts: !!set {8082/tcp: null}
    image: cicd/my-fake-service:latest
    killContainer: false
    manual: false
    networkMode: arquillian-cub_default
    networks: [arquillian-cub_default]
    portBindings: !!set {9191->8080/tcp: null}
    readonlyRootfs: false
    removeVolumes: true
networks:
```

arquillian-cub_default: {driver: bridge}

I am geting ERROR while running tests:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No port was specified and in all containers there are more than one bind port.
 at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.util.SinglePortBindResolver.resolvePortBindPort(SinglePortBindResolver.java:161)**

Would appreciate help on this. I know I am missing something here

Comment: docker-compose.yml .      version: '3'
services:
    fake:
      image: cicd/my-fake-service:latest
      expose: 
        - "8082"
      ports:
        - "9191:8080"
    tomcat:
      image: tutum/tomcat:7.0
      ports: 
        - "8181:8080"

Comment: It turns out that I needed to use following in my arquillian.xml in order to get restAssured initialized correctly, <extension qualifier="restassured">
  <property name="port">1000</property>
 </extension>